# Opera - Print web page to PDF without the title and footer?

Tags: windows, linux, opera

I am using Opera 11.64 and 12 and I want to remove the title and footer text when printing to PDF. In Firefox, I can customize the PDF before it is printed, but such settings aren't as apparent in Opera. I only want the content. How can I remove the title, date, page number, and URL when printing to PDF?

Comment: Which version of Opera?

Comment: @iglvzx: My Opera version is 11.64 and 12. I'm using it mainly in Linux.

Comment: Great. Thanks for also adding this info to your question.

Comment: To clarify, the title and footer are included when you use Print Preview or a different printer? I'm guessing this is not strictly related to PDF.

Comment: Do you mean what Aardvark is doing? https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/aardvark-for-opera/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the header and footer by going to `opera:config` and disabling the `Show Printer Header` preference. Be sure to **save** the changes!

[image: header]

**Note:** You could also **clear** the individual `Print Left Header String`, `Print Right Header String`, `Print Left Footer String` and `Print Right Footer String` fields.

Answer (score 2):

To just disable header and footer completely you could simply untick *Print->Print Options->Print headers and footers*. Using the Preferences Editor is only necessary if you want to customize header and footer.